# Error: Main method not found in class java.lang.String

Tags: java, runtime-error

I tried to implement this code:

```
package java.lang;
public class String {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
         {
            String str= "1";
         }
     }
}
```

But I'm getting

> Error: Main method not found in class java.lang.String, please define
>   the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

I've googled and tried everything, but don't know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class name from `String` to something other than that. `String` is already a keyword in java.

```
package java.lang;
    public class S1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         for (int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
             {
                String str= "1";
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid using the package java.lang as well.

And change the name class to something other than `String`.

Answer (score 2):

`String` is already defined as a final class in java; as part of the `java.lang` package.

You could use the class name `String` elsewhere (i.e. your own packages) but not as any of your `java.lang` package classes.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. No need to do `package java.lang;` And you should implement either a whole subpackage like `package java.somePackage.*` or just a specific class `package java.net.HttpURLConnection`. Importing packages unnecessarily is a bad practice. Seems like you are new to Java, get your good standards as accurately from the scratch as possible.
2. Change your classname to something else, as suggested by other answer providers. `String` is a fundamental class (not primitive type). It is more like static class library for general use.
3. The rest is fine. I am a bit confused about your statement within `for` loop. But it is syntactically correct. We are not responsible for that.

Should be fine now!